# How/why does matrix multiplication work to do a linear fit?

Tags: linear-algebra, image-processing, linear-regression

Some background: I have a B.S. in physics. I have taken linear algebra. I do work that involves doing image analysis in IDL.

One thing I have to do a lot is fit a linear equation $(y=mx+b)$ to the number of electronic counts accumulated in each pixel over a series of frames. So, usually I'm working with something like an array that's $4096\times 4096\times 100$. Until now I've been just running a for loop where I input the hundred values for each pixel and a time vector into a linfit or regress function which spits out the linear fit. I then write the slope of that fit to a new $4096\times 4096 $ image which shows the rate each pixel accumulates counts/charge. It works, but a for loop that runs $16$ million times is slow in IDL.

Now, of course this is not a new problem and I found a nice procedure written by someone at the Space Telescope Science Institute that does the same thing as above but with really fast matrix multiplication. I've tested it and it gives the results I expect. Problem is that I don't understand how it works, and so can't modify it to fit my needs.

As far as I can tell the program is using this linear regression using matrices:

[Linear Regression in Matrix Form](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~jennings/stat514/stat512notes/topic3.pdf)

Unfortunately, I struggle with matrices; thus, I can't make any sense of what's happening.

There's the added difficulty that to do this in IDL the $4096\times 4096\times N$ array is turned into a $4096*4096\times N$ array (that is ~$16.7$million by $N$) and I'm not quite sure why.

So, can anyone explain what this matrix math is doing in extremely simple terms? For bonus points, avoid using terms like "null", "kernel", "space", and try not to just post a long series of formulas as my eyes will probably just glaze over. As a preemptive against those who might tell me that I need to study more Linear Algebra: I have and I aced the undergrad class. I have no problem with the mechanics of it. I just don't understand the underlying motivation and concepts of linear algebra.

Here is a link to the code: [ramp_basiclinfit.pro](http://www.stsci.edu/~robberto/Main/Software/IDL4pipeline/ramp_basiclinfit-code.html)

Comment: You need to study more *theoretical* linear algebra. Congrats on getting an A in a computational class, but if you don't understand this you clearly understand very little linear algebra. Understanding how to multiple matrices is not understanding linear algebra any more than understanding basic calculus is understanding Lagrangian mechanics. Asking people to not use words that refer to key concepts in a field is another good sign you don't understand the field.

Comment: Additionally, googling "linear algebra matrix regression" brings up this page: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/382 can you understand this? It answers your question. If you have read a resource, such as this link, and still have questions, it's far more useful for you to explain what it is that you don't understand, and if you haven't read such a source, perhaps you should try.

Comment: It might be easier to explain if you post the pseudocode of what you are doing and what the procedure you found is doing. By the way, what is IDL?

Comment: Stella - Obviously I don't understand. That's why I'm asking, to get help from people like yourself to get a better understanding. If you clicked the link in my original post you would see that it's very similar to the one you posted. I have read it through the linear regression part a few times. I understand what is happening, but not why. So you're right, I don't understand. Posting this question is part of me trying to understand.

Comment: Calle - IDL is a programming language used a lot in astronomy. It just happens to be what I work with. It could easily be replaced with something like python or Matlab. I thought about putting a description of the code in the original question. I will try to do that. Maybe it will help me understand what is happening in the code to try to explain it.

Comment: Everyone - If my question is not well formed, I apologize. I am open to suggestions of how to improve what I'm asking. But, I'm not sure how comments about how I lack understanding are helpful. If I understood linear algebra well I wouldn't be asking the question. I assure you I'm well aware of my own shortcomings in math.

Comment: Yeah guys, I agree with Chris. He has a concrete problem (or rather a solution) he needs to understand. To understand this, he might have to dive deeper on some aspects. It does not help him, nor is it very constructive, to point out that he needs to "learn more about X".

Comment: A starting point is to understand how matrix multiplication "works" to express a system of linear equations as a single vector-valued equation.  It is not a deep concept, but it is a bit more substantial than just a change of notation.  The idea of "multiplying" a row times a column to get a scalar is the crux of matrix multiplication, and it happens to capture the details of a linear system in a concise but useful form.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is given on page 4, "Parameter Estimation - Least Squares".

You want to solve a system of linear equations, which can be written in matrix form as
$$
X u = y \quad (*)
$$
This is a compact notation for $m$ rows of linear equation $\sum_j x_{ij} u_j = y_i$ in $n$ variables $u_j$. It can be interpreted as a linear transformation $X$ acting on a vector $u$, mapping it to the vector $y$.

In your case the equations of the linear regression problem can be grouped such that they form a matrix equation like equation $(*)$. The vector of unknowns $u$ would hold the coefficients of the solution of the linear regression. Solving that system for $u$ would give the coefficients
for a perfect fit.

It can happen that an exact solution $u$ is not possible for various reasons, but an approximative solution vector $\beta$ is considered which results in an image vector $X \beta = \hat{y}$ which might be different from the goal vector $y$.

So we have a difference 
$$
\epsilon = y - \hat{y} = y - X \beta
$$
which we want to have as small as possible.

Thus one minimizes the expression 
\begin{align}
d(\beta) 
&= \lVert \epsilon \rVert_2^2 \\
&= \sum_i \epsilon_i^2 \\
&= \sum_i (y - X \beta)_i^2 \\
&= (y - X \beta)^T (y - X \beta)
\end{align} 
which is the squared length of the error vector in the $2$-norm, which 
depends on the choice of $\beta$. 
This form is what the term "least squares" refers to.

For a local extremum of $d(\beta)$, the gradient $\partial d / \partial \beta$ has to vanish (the equivalent to $f'(x) = 0$ in one dimension). And this happens if $\beta$ is a solution of another linear system that we get by multiplying both sides of the matrix equation $(*)$ from the left with the transposed matrix $X^T$:
$$
X^T X \beta = X^T y
$$
This new system has the matrix $A = X^T X$, a square $n \times n$ matrix, and the image vector $b = X^T y$. The really nice property of that new 
system 
$$
A \beta = b
$$ 
is that $A = X^T X$ is invertible. There are algorithms to derive the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ for a given matrix $A$. So we can solve
for $\beta$:
$$
\beta = A^{-1} b = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T y
$$

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what you need. Here it is the answer to your problems:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkfY0OKH12g

Comment: Yep, this is very helpful. I need things explained slowly and in words, not formulas, or at least formulas with lots of explanation of what each term in the formula means.